# Dynamic link is not working on real ios device for custom domain

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

There is custom domain created as a url prefix and added dynamic links for screen navigation,it's working fine for Android but not on ios using react native.

Did following steps

1.Project setting in firebase w.r.t app store id, team id and bundle id.

2.Checked hosting in firebase.

3. Added Associated domain in xcode.

4.Added firebase dynamic link key in info.plist file with dynamic links.